# Can a transaction column formula field update after line item is added? Or only after record save

Tags: netsuite

I wanted to create a "Total Line" field on the expense report expense line that adds in the amount from the taxes to the subtotal "amount" to give a total for that specific expense.
My problem though, is that after you add the line, it is blank.
It only works after you save the record, but this is not that helpful for staff as they are entering their expenses.
Is this a limitation of NetSuite?
Would I have to put in a script that somehow refreshes the record after a line is added? I'm not familiar with scripting.

The formula is {amount} + ({amount} * {taxrate1}) + ({amount} * {taxrate2})

The field id is custcol_total_line

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKrRX.jpg

Comment: You can definitely do this in script. But to try and stay on your formula field can you provide the formula you are trying ?

Comment: Thanks 

It's {amount} + ({amount} * {taxrate1}) + ({amount} * {taxrate2})

The field id is custcol_total_line

Comment: @TMann any chance you could give me a suggestion for the script? It looks like you know what you're doing! Thanks so much

Comment: yea the script is easy. You can have a field change function that fires of amount changes. You would get the values of each function and then do your math and set your calculated amount in your new field. I will try and write the code and post as an answer later. FYI - I saw you just posted this question again with the script info. Generally you don't want to make 2 posts for the same thing. People see it as a duplicate on here and may down vote or even close the question. Best to have one

Comment: @TMann thanks so much! I deleted the other question.  I was wondering if recalc automatically looks at a change in the total amount? Maybe I misread that. I started trying to make my own (and I know nothing about scripts) but this was it. function recalc(,'myrecalc'){  
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custcol_total_line', '{amount} + ({amount} * {taxrate1}) + ({amount} * {taxrate2})');
}

Comment: if you do find my below answer useful, please mark it as the best answer on the left side of the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the field changed function I would use. I would make this a Client Script using this below function. This would currently fire if the amount on the line is changed.

```
/**
 * The recordType (internal id) corresponds to the "Applied To" record in your script deployment. 
 * @appliedtorecord recordType
 * 
 * @param {String} type Sublist internal id
 * @param {String} name Field internal id
 * @param {Number} linenum Optional line item number, starts from 1
 * @returns {Void}
 */
function clientFieldChanged(type, name, linenum){
    if(type == 'item' && name == 'amount'){
        var amount = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','amount', linenum);
        var taxRate1 = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','taxrate1', linenum);
        var taxRate2 = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','taxrate2', linenum);

        var totalLineAmt = amount + (amount*taxRate1) + (amount*taxRate2);
        nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_total_line', linenum, totalLineAmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @TMann , so I've added this on the expense record form under custom code as "total_line_stackoverflow.js" and under the FIELD CHANGED FUNTION I have "clientFieldChanged". Do I need to do anything else to make this work? It doesn't appear to be working when I'm adding expense lines. Thanks again

Comment: @gabe17, did you create a Script Deployment record?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the above to work, so I asked NetSuite for their help, and this is what we ended up with if it's useful to anyone else. We did it as a validate line function. and I added it to the custom code on the expense report form. Thanks so much for your help @TMAnn

```
function validatetotalline(type){
    if(type == 'expense'){
    var amount = parseFloat(nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('expense','amount'));
    var taxRate1 = parseFloat(nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('expense','taxrate1'));
    var taxRate2 = parseFloat(nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('expense','taxrate2'));

    var totalLineAmt = (amount) + (amount*taxRate1/100) + (amount*taxRate2/100);
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('expense', 'custcol_total_line', totalLineAmt);
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: no problem. Sorry I didn't see your followup questions. I forgot about the parseFloat and didn't get to test this in my account. Glad that my code gave you the good start to get to where you needed. Thanks!

Comment: @TMann 

It turns out that this script stops NetSuite's drag and drop file functionality because it's running for all sublists including adding a file, and it doesn't know what to do with this script.

NetSuite looked at the issue, but I have to admit I don't understand their response. It says...

Comment: "The reason why the 'add' button gets disabled is with the If(type == 'expense') line where expense is not a valid type as it implies the actual type of record. The list under the Apply tab also can not be used with nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue as it is an entirely different record as you can not extract the type from it. 

To check which fields are scriptable for any type of record, you may refer to the records browser, see Id 10511 (Working with the SuiteScript Records Browser) "
Would you have an idea of how to fix this? Would I need to say if the 'amount' field is greater than 0?